# How to use CTest on MacOS without disabling SIP (no `LC_PATH` is set)

Tags: macos, cmake, intel-mkl, ctest

I have unit tests written using CTest that depend on Intel's MKL BLAS implementation. I use `find_package(BLAS)` and link the test executables to `${BLAS_LIBRARIES}`. The test executables depend on the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to find the `mkl` libraries, rather than an embedded `LC_RPATH`.

Unfortunately, because of `SIP`, the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not propagated to the `ctest` environment, so when it tries to run the tests it fails to link the `mkl` libraries.

Is there a way to get `CMake` to embed an external `LC_PATH` for test executables in the build directory?

Here's a basic test executable (test.cpp)

```cpp
#include <mkl_cblas.h>

int main() {
  return &cblas_dgemm != nullptr;
}
```

and here is the associated `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14.5)

project(blas LANGUAGES CXX)
include(CTest)

set(BLA_VENDOR Intel10_64lp_seq)
find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)

add_executable(test_blas test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_blas ${BLAS_LIBRARIES})

add_test(NAME test_direct COMMAND test_blas)
```

I find `MKL` and build without any issues.

```sh
Lukes-MacBook:test ldalessa$ cmake .
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.1.10010046
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Looking for sgemm_
-- Looking for sgemm_ - found
-- Found BLAS: /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.233/mac/mkl/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib;/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.233/mac/mkl/lib/libmkl_sequential.dylib;/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.233/mac/mkl/lib/libmkl_core.dylib;-lm;-ldl  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/ldalessa/test
Lukes-MacBook:test ldalessa$ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.14.5/bin/cmake -S/Users/ldalessa/test -B/Users/ldalessa/test --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.14.5/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/ldalessa/test/CMakeFiles /Users/ldalessa/test/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/test_blas.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/test_blas.dir/depend
cd /Users/ldalessa/test && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.14.5/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/ldalessa/test /Users/ldalessa/test /Users/ldalessa/test /Users/ldalessa/test /Users/ldalessa/test/CMakeFiles/test_blas.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependee "/Users/ldalessa/test/CMakeFiles/test_blas.dir/DependInfo.cmake" is newer than depender "/Users/ldalessa/test/CMakeFiles/test_blas.dir/depend.internal".
Dependee "/Users/ldalessa/test/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "/Users/ldalessa/test/CMakeFiles/test_blas.dir/depend.internal".
Scanning dependencies of target test_blas
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/test_blas.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/test_blas.dir/build
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test_blas.dir/test.cpp.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk   -o CMakeFiles/test_blas.dir/test.cpp.o -c /Users/ldalessa/test/test.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable test_blas
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.14.5/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/test_blas.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/test_blas.dir/test.cpp.o  -o test_blas /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.233/mac/mkl/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.233/mac/mkl/lib/libmkl_sequential.dylib /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.233/mac/mkl/lib/libmkl_core.dylib -lm -ldl 
[100%] Built target test_blas
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.14.5/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/ldalessa/test/CMakeFiles 0
Lukes-MacBook:test ldalessa$ ./test_blas 
Lukes-MacBook:test ldalessa$
```

But when I run with `CTest` I have the `SIP` issue.

```
ukes-MacBook:test ldalessa$ make test
Running tests...
Test project /Users/ldalessa/test
    Start 1: test_direct
1/1 Test #1: test_direct ......................Child aborted***Exception:   0.01 sec

0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.01 sec

The following tests FAILED:
      1 - test_direct (Child aborted)
Errors while running CTest
make: *** [test] Error 8
Lukes-MacBook:test ldalessa$ cat Testing/Temporary/LastTest.log 
Start testing: Jun 10 03:35 PDT
----------------------------------------------------------
1/1 Testing: test_direct
1/1 Test: test_direct
Command: "/Users/ldalessa/test/test_blas"
Directory: /Users/ldalessa/test
"test_direct" start time: Jun 10 03:35 PDT
Output:
----------------------------------------------------------
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/ldalessa/test/test_blas
  Reason: image not found
<end of output>
Test time =   0.01 sec
----------------------------------------------------------
Test Failed.
"test_direct" end time: Jun 10 03:35 PDT
"test_direct" time elapsed: 00:00:00
----------------------------------------------------------

End testing: Jun 10 03:35 PDT
Lukes-MacBook:test ldalessa$
```

Comment: I still need and answer to this, but my temporary workaround for this is currently to use Apple's Accelerate framework instead of MKL, which links properly. The problem is that this is intrusive as Intel's MKL uses different headers (`mkl_blas.h`, `mkl_lapack.h`) and symbol names so I have to have some extra configure time and configured header nonsense to adapt the code base.

Answer (score 0):

I received [this solution](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2019-July/069755.html) through the cmake mailing list. Basically the solution is to extract the path to the mkl library directory using some cmake magic and then manually add that path to the BUILD_RPATH.

```
list(GET BLAS_LIBRARIES 0 _BLAS_FIRSTLIB)
get_filename_component(_BLAS_LIBDIR "${_BLAS_FIRSTLIB}" DIRECTORY)
set_target_properties(test_blas PROPERTIES BUILD_RPATH "${_BLAS_LIBDIR}")
```